# When click my LMB, it keeps split areas

Tags: selection-tools, mouse

When I click the LMB, it keeps split new areas that I can't select an object now. (As status bar shown in the left-bottom.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the Edit-Preferences-screen.
Seems I accidentally clicked on something for adding LMB setting into the preferences.